# How draw a black ball in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I drew some colorful balls using OvalShape and RadialGradient. Here are the result:
[image: some colorful balls]

All balls are good, except that the black ones look like flat. How to draw a shining black ball in Android? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to experiment with shape color for black ball.

Comment: Try to put dark-gray on black one

Answer (score 0):

The other ones look really good.

For the black balls, use dark grey instead of black. With the gradient in place it will look correct.